# Issue with "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)" with a content type with a repeated taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have and issue with the view filter "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)".
In my view I'm filtering a content type who as two fields represented by the same taxonomy, and that view filter (Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)), do the filter of the union of all the values in the two fields of the same taxonomy. For example:

---

Taxonomy "Subjects":

deparment1

- subject11
- subject12
- ...
- subject1n

deparment2

- subject21
- subject22
- ...
- subject2n

deparment3

- subject31
- subject32
- ...
- subject3n

---

Custom type: **Annual enrollment**

Fields:

...

Subjects enrolled on first period (reference to term Subjects and multivalue)

Subjects enrolled on second period (reference to term Subjects and multivalue)

...

---

View: Filter for enrollments

...

Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)(exposed)

...

---

For example, in this case, that filter (associated with a Taxonomy and not a content type field) will filter the results for the departments in both subjects enrolled on first and second period, and what I want is that the filter only affects one field (in my real case, I need two of these filters, one for each field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that the view filter *Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)* search in the `taxonomy_index` table instead of a field of the content type, so I ended duplicating the [*Simple hierarchical select module*](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) (SHS) who's behavior is equal to the *Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)*, and editing the query it does.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: a "person" content type with two taxonomy term fields (place of birth and place of residence) related to the same vocabulary (provinces and towns), rendered through Simple Hierarchical Select.

I don't understand how you solved it, how you set the view to filter "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)" just with one taxonomy field.

Thank you